# GIT: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have two branches one is called master the other is called dev
I am currently in the master branch and I want to go to the dev branch to move a file to the development server. however when I perform a

```
$ git checkout dev
```

I get the message:

> The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by
>   checkout:
>
> ```
> pages/memclub/images/subheaders/leadership.png
> pages/memclub/images/subheaders/male.png
> pages/memclub/images/subheaders/marketing.png
> pages/memclub/images/subheaders/training.png
> ```

I dont want to commit the files to the master, they are not ready to be pushed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First you'll want to add the files in question so that they're tracked by Git (you don't have to commit any changes, but Git needs to know about the files):

```
git add pages/memclub/images/subheaders/leadership.png pages/memclub/images/subheaders/male.png 
git add pages/memclub/images/subheaders/marketing.png pages/memclub/images/subheaders/training.png
```

Then you can stash your changes:

```
git stash
```

When you're ready to start working on the files again, you can use:

```
git stash pop
```

Comment: when trying the git stash - get the error: No local changes to save

Comment: Oh, right, because your files are untracked.  You'll have to `git add` them first, then stash.  You don't have to commit them, but you do have to add them.

Comment: Insead of `git stash pop` you can also use `git stash apply`. Pop will pop out your files from stash but apply will copy files from stash

Comment: knoxxs, `git stash pop` and `git stash apply` are synonyms; they don't do anything differently.

Comment: @EthanBrown that's not true, @knoxxs is right.

From the documentation: `Like pop, but do not remove the state from the stash list. Unlike pop, <stash> may be any commit that looks like a commit created by stash save or stash create.`

Comment: Instead of adding the files, you can also use `git stash --include-untracked` (or `-u` for short).