# After migrating servers, git does not show, did a git init, but now I can't change to master

Tags: git

I migrated servers for my files but when I did, somehow the git config files were missing.

I did a git init and set the remote url to the proper repo, but even after a git fetch, it is not on the master branch and I'm unable to switch to the master branch so git recognizes all of the files as new.

How do I get git to recognize the current files as part of the master branch?

I can't do a git clone to start over because I've already since added code to the files and need to keep the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: [Git: can't switch between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364597/git-cant-switch-between-branches)

I just had to do a force git checkout

```
git checkout -f master
```