# How to fix untracked working tree error while checking out?

Tags: git

I have two branches one for developing and other for staging. I first checkout the `developing` branch and then build some files on it and then checkouts `staging` branch and push the new files to  `staging`

```
git checkout develop
#
# Run some build scripts here
#
git fetch origin staging:staging
git checkout staging
git add *
git commit -m "new commits"
```

but its giving this error

```
error: Untracked working tree file * would be overwritten by checkout.
                            file.1
                            file.2
                            file.3
```

file.1 and file.2 and file.3 doesn't exist in `develop` branch but it creates after the build script runs and it also exists in `staging`.

I tried multiple ways to solve this problem. I tried force checking out `git checkout --force staging` but it exits with nothing to update message. Then I tried this

```
git fetch origin staging:staging
git stash
git reset --hard
git checkout staging
git add --all
git commit -m "new commits"
```

which also fails

ERROR

```
Auto-merging newfile.xx
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in newfile.xx
On branch staging
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    both added:      newfile.xx
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323348/7976758 (add, *no commit*, stash push, checkout, stash pop): `git add file.* && git stash && git checkout staging && git stash pop`

Comment: It partially worked but I am getting error in one file `newfile.xx`

Comment: I recommend `git worktree`, by which you can checkout each branch into separate directories while they share the same `.git`.

Comment: I doubt that you really mean `git add *`.

Comment: @Eka: the second sequence of commands you mention will not create a merge conflict. Did you forget to post one of your git commands ? like `git stash pop` or `git merge develop` ?